# SQL Error in PHP - get_sql undefined variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have some problem here..The error is undefined variable line 168 i m beginner in this programming langguage..When i click icon to view the data, this error will come out..may someone help me.? Here is the code..

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('../include/page_header2.php'); 
$id = $_GET['id'];

$maid_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maid WHERE id = '".$id."'");
$get_maid = mysql_fetch_assoc($maid_q);
$maid = $get_maid['full_name'];
?>

<style>
.submit_style {
    color : #eee;
    padding:4px;
    border : none;
    // Where are you getting this "IMAGE_PATH" vvv
    background:transparent url("<?php echo IMAGE_PATH.'remove.png'; ?>") no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size:21px 21px;
    text-indent: -1000em;
    width:25px;
}
</style>
<script>
function goLastMonth(month, year, id){
if(month == 1) {
--year;
month = 13;
}
--month // Missing ;
var monthstring= ""+month+"";
var monthlength = monthstring.length;
if(monthlength <=1){
monthstring = "0" + monthstring;
}
document.location.href ="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year+"&id="+id;
}
function goNextMonth(month, year, id){
if(month == 12) {
++year;
month = 0;
}
++month // Missing ;
var monthstring= ""+month+"";
var monthlength = monthstring.length;
if(monthlength <=1){
monthstring = "0" + monthstring;
}

// You need to echo this "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"
 document.location.href ="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year+"&id="+id;
}
</script>
<style>
.today{
background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.event{
background-color: #AFE2FE;
}
#session_list{
font-size:8px;
}
#name_list{
font-size:7px;
}
a{text-decoration:none; color: #000000}
a:active{ text-decoration:none; color: #000000}
a:hover{ text-decoration:none; color: #000000}
</style>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['day'])){
$day = $_GET['day'];
} else {
$day = date("j");
}
if(isset($_GET['month'])){
$month = $_GET['month'];
} else {
$month = date("n");
}
if(isset($_GET['year'])){
$year = $_GET['year'];
}else{
$year = date("Y");
}
$currentTimeStamp = strtotime( "$day-$month-$year");
$monthName = date("F", $currentTimeStamp);
$numDays = date("t", $currentTimeStamp);
$counter = 0;
?>
<title>L.T.K. Cleaning System</title><div align="center">
<table width="80%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" >
    <tr>
        <td width="14.3%"><div align="right"><input type='button' value=' < 'name='previousbutton' class="all_btn" onclick ="goLastMonth(<?php echo $month.",".$year.",".$id ?>)"></div></td> // Missing ;
        <td colspan="5"><div align="center"><?php echo $monthName.", ".$year; ?></div></td>
        <td width="14.3%"><input type='button' value=' > 'name='nextbutton' class="all_btn" onclick ="goNextMonth(<?php echo $month.",".$year.",".$id?>)" /></td> // Missing ;
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="80%" class="tableFormat2" id="main_tbl2" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" frame="box">
    <tr>
        <th width="14.3%">Sun</th>
        <th width="14.3%">Mon</th>
        <th width="14.3%">Tue</th>
        <th width="14.3%">Wed</th>
        <th width="14.3%">Thu</th>
        <th width="14.3%">Fri</th>
        <th width="14.3%">Sat</th>
    </tr>
<?php
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++, $counter++)
    {
        $timeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$i");

        if($i == 1) 
        {
            $firstDay = date("w", $timeStamp);

            for($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++)
            {
                echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
        }

        if($counter % 7 == 0)
        {
            echo"</tr><tr>";
        }

        $monthstring = $month;
        $monthlength = strlen($monthstring);
        $daystring = $i;
        $daylength = strlen($daystring);

        if($monthlength <= 1)
        {
            $monthstring = "0".$monthstring;
        }

        if($daylength <=1)
        {
            $daystring = "0".$daystring;
        }

        $todaysDate = date("Y-m-d");
        $dateToCompare = $year. '-' . $monthstring. '-' . $daystring;
        echo "<td valign='top' align='right' ";

        if ($todaysDate == $dateToCompare)
        {
            echo "class ='today'";
        } 
        else
        {   
            $sqlCount = "select * from service where recurring_date LIKE '%".$dateToCompare."%' and available_maid like '%$maid%'";
            $get_sql = mysql_query($sqlCount);
            $noOfEvent = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sqlCount));
            if($noOfEvent >= 1)
            {
                echo "class='event'";
            }
        }

        echo ">";       


        echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?year=".$year."&month=".$monthstring."&day=".$daystring."&id=".$id."&v=true'>".$i."<br />";
        while($session_q = mysql_fetch_array($get_sql)){
        $count1++; // Can't find this declared?
        $customer_id= $session_q['customer_id'];
            $sqlcust1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer where id = '$customer_id' ");
            $get_custinfo1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlcust1);
            echo "<table name='schedulelist' id='schedulelist' class='schedulelist'><tr valign ='top'><td><div id='name_list'>";?>
            // Where are you getting vvv
            <img src=<?php echo IMAGE_PATH.'dot.png'; ?> width="5"/>
            <?php 
            echo $get_custinfo1['customer_name']."</div></td>";
            echo "<td>";
            $maid_name=explode(",",$session_q['available_maid']);
            $countmaid=count($maid_name);
            for($maidi=0;$maidi<$countmaid;$maidi++)
            {       
            echo "<div id='name_list'>";?>
            <img src=<?php echo IMAGE_PATH.'dot.png'; ?> width="5"/>
            <?php
            echo $maid_name[$maidi];
            echo "</div>";
            } 
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<div id='name_list'>";
            echo $session_q['service_session']."</div>";
            echo "</td></tr></table>"; 

        }?><input type="hidden" name="ctr" id="ctr" value="<?php echo $count1; ?>"> // Again, can't find $count1 declared
        <?php 
        echo "</a></td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
?>
</table>

<?php
    if(isset($_GET['v'])) 
    {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['day'] =$day;
    $_SESSION['month'] =$month;
    $_SESSION['year'] =$year;

$maid_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maid WHERE id = '".$id."'");
$get_maid = mysql_fetch_assoc($maid_q);
$maid = $get_maid['full_name'];

        $sqlEvent = "select * FROM service where recurring_date LIKE '%".$year."-".$month."-".$day."%' and available_maid like '%$maid%'";

        $resultEvents = mysql_query($sqlEvent);
        echo "<br />Occupancy for <strong>".$day." ".$monthName." ".$year."</strong><br />";
?>
<table class='tableFormat' id='main_tbl' width='80%'>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <?php
        if($_SESSION['login_level'] == 'Admin')
        {
        ?>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all"></th>
        <th>Service Session</th>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th style="color:#609;"><label id="selected_item"></label></th>
    </tr>
<?php
        $counter = '';

        while ($events = mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents))
        {
            $counter++;
?>

            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
                <?php
                    if($_SESSION['login_level'] == 'Admin')
                    {
                ?>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="id_<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="id_<?php echo $counter; ?>" value="<?php echo $events['id']; ?>" onclick="check(this.value)"></td>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <td><?php echo $events['service_session']; ?></td>
                <td><?php 
                    $customer_id= $events['customer_id'];
                    $sqlcust = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer where id = '$customer_id' ");
                    $get_custinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlcust);
                    echo $get_custinfo['customer_name']; 
                    ?>              </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="view_service.php?id=<?php echo $events['id']; ?>" target="_self"><img src=<?php echo IMAGE_PATH.'view.png'; ?> width="17" title="View Details" id="view"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php   
        }
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="ctr" id="ctr" value="<?php echo $counter; ?>">
</table>

<?php 
}
?>

<br />
<input type="button" name="close" id="close" value="Close" class="all_btn" onClick="window.parent.location.href='maid.php'">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bc').html("<a href='booking.php'>Scheduled Service</a>");

    $("#customer").autocomplete("auto_custName.php", {
        width: 270,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('.nm3').nyroModal({});
});

$("#select_all").click(function() {

    $counter = $("#ctr").val(); // This is not PHP here. Why the '$' ??

    if($('#select_all').is(':checked'))
    {
        for($i = 1; $i <= $counter; $i++) // This is not PHP here. Why the '$' ??
        {
            $("#id_" + $i).attr('checked', true);
        }
        $("#selected_item").html($counter + " selected" + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="sub-del" id="sub-del" class="submit_style" value="sub-del" title="Delete All" style="color:#eee;">');
    }else
    {
        for($i = 1; $i <= $counter; $i++) // This is not PHP here. Why the '$' ??
        {
            $("#id_" + $i).attr('checked', false); // This is not PHP here. Why the '$' ??
        }
        $('#selected_item').text('');
    }
});

function check(id)
{
    $counter = $("#ctr").val(); // This is not PHP here. Why the '$' ??
    $ctr = 0; // This is not PHP here. Why the '$' ??

    for($i = 1; $i <= $counter; $i++) // This is not PHP here. Why the '$' ??
    {
        if($('#id_'+$i).is(':checked')) // This is not PHP here. Why the '$' ??
        {
            $ctr++; // This is not PHP here. Why the '$' ??
        }
    }

    if($ctr > 0) // This is not PHP here. Why the '$' ??
    {
        $("#selected_item").html($ctr + " selected" + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="sub-del" id="sub-del" class="submit_style" value="sub-del" title="Delete All" style="color:#eee;">');
    }else
    {
        $("#selected_item").text("");   
    }
}

function deleteConfirmation(name, id){
    $id = id;
    $.confirm({
        'title'     : 'Delete Confirmation',
        'message'   : 'Are you sure want to delete ' + name + ' scheduled service record?',
        'buttons'   : {
            'Yes'   : {
            'class' : 'blue',
            'action': function(){
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            action: 'delete_service',
                            id: $id,
                        },
                        url: 'action.php',
                        success: function(){
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            'No'    : {
                'class' : 'gray',
                'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you write us what is line 168 pls

Comment: I added some comments to your script pointing out some issues I see right off the bat.